# how to plot a bar graph of attributes of node in R

Tags: r

how can i plot a bar graph in R, with specific attributes of specific node?
i have a gml file like this:

```
graph [
  node [
    id 0
    label "Apple"
    year 1997
    bold 1
    normal 4
    light 15
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "Apple"
    year 2000
    bold 2
    normal 16    
    light 2
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "BBC"
    year 2010
    bold 18
    normal 2
    light 0 
  ]
]
```

and i run this R script,i have troubles when i need to extract attributes value from a node selection:

```
install.packages(c("igraph"))
library(igraph)

g = read.graph(file = "/media/Data/TEMP/R_test/test.gml", format = "gml")

apple = V(g)$label[V(g)$label == "Apple"]
table(apple)

for(i in seq(along=apple)){
  mL = apple[,i]$bold
  L = apple[,i]$normal
  pL = apple[,i]$light

  barplot(????)
}
```

how can i fix this script?thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a barplot of bolds per year for Apple:

```
df <- subset(as_data_frame(g, "vertices"), label=="Apple", c(year, bold))
barplot(df$bold, names.arg = df$year, main = "Apple")
```

Comment: thx, how can i set the data to plot a **Stacked Bar**, like have for every year the attributes[bold,normal,light] in the same column? i need to create a table?

Comment: E.g. `df <- subset(as_data_frame(g, "vertices"), label=="Apple", c(year, bold, normal, light)); barplot(as.matrix(t(df[, -1])), names.arg = df$year, main = "Apple")`.